# Print diferent site logo depending on the language

Tags: theming, 8

I have two logo. One logo for ENG and one logo for another language.

How to print diferent logo on page depending on the language?

Does I need to put some if function who would checks language or there is some easier way?

Below is my code for printing logo in Drupal 8 with Twig.

```
function acton_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
      $variables['logopath'] = '/' . drupal_get_path('theme','acton') . '/logo-eng.png';
    }
```

In my Twig template, I do this:

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="{{ logopath }}" />
```

Comment: I would create a block and do it that way since otherwise you would have issue with caching.

Comment: @IvanJaros Thank you on suggestion. Good thinking. I would do like that.